# Getting Nexus S Android NFC into Card emulation mode

Tags: android, mode, emulation, nfc

Has anyone been able to get the nexus s into card emulation mode?

The latest android release does not seem to support this yet.

This article says it's possible http://www.nearfieldcommunicationsworld.com/2011/02/13/35913/uncovered-the-hidden-nfc-potential-of-the-google-nexus-s-and-the-nokia-c7/

Answer (score 6):

Long story short:

Yes, it's possible, but only if you hack. The article you've posted shows how it's done.

Such a hack will only work with the Nexus-S, and only on modified phones with android 2.3.3 Everything relies on undocumented framework classes that may change anytime.

With the official android SDK it is not possible.

Answer (score 2):

Here you can download a patch for Gingerbread who enable card emulation :
http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/d5fc35a9f16aa467/dec4843abd73d9e9%3Flnk%3Dgst%26q%3Dsecure%2Belement%2Bdiff%2527s%23dec4843abd73d9e9

The emulated card will be Mifare Classic 4K.

Answer (score 2):

There are many questions around NFC card emulation on Android. Some doubts were solved [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6611810/nfc-card-emulation-android/6690356#6690356). So far all my findinds are summarized [in this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6992869/android-and-symbian-nfc-mobile-development-questions-and-answers-faq/7595889#7595889).

Answer (score 1):

I think with card emulation you mean the P2P mode. Android 2.3.3+ has limited support for that, you can push NDEF messages and make the phoen appear as it was a passive nfc tag. You can write and read from 2.3.3 on by the way. No more hacking.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to enable card-emulation mode on the Nexus S. I will post more information about the process on xda-developers.

However, after a lot of hacking, I was only able to force some fixed data on the SE (Secure Element). I also force the SE to have a fixed ID. On an unhacked Nexus S, the ID changes all the time.

When I tried to read the Card-emulated Nexus S, using an NFC Shield on Arduino, I got the ID of the card and the forced data on the SE. However, when I tried to read my phone using another Nexus S, the phone was not even detected.

The "forced fixed data" on the SE can only be set within the source code of Android, in my attempt. I have not yet found a way to write data to the SE using an android application.

Comment: hi @shailenTJ, sorry to wake up this post. This is because Android by default tries to force P2P mode. I have managed to activate emulation mode on Nexus-S as well. But struggling to force data. Could you share how you force data and fixed UID on SE?