# Android NFC, secure element on SD card

Tags: android, sd-card, nfc, smartcard, rfid

Does anybody see the possibility to enable (by enable I mean even compile the sources, e.g. as shown by Gerald Madlmayr on the http://www.nearfieldcommunicationsworld.com/2011/02/13/35913/uncovered-the-hidden-nfc-potential-of-the-google-nexus-s-and-the-nokia-c7/) the NFC NXP 544 to work in card emulation mode not using the SWP and UICC for SE as shown in the article, but using the SE on the microSD?

For this there is dedicated protocol S2C, but I would like to stick the the traditional SD card with the SE like the Mobile Security Card from G&D ( http://www.gi-de.com/en/products_and_solutions/products/secure_microsd/product_details_4992.jsp). It contains SE, which can be accessed by the standard file I/O commands, which are APDUs 'decorated' by specific 'magic' numbers, so they are by the SD card micro controller distinguished from other file I/O and those commands are send directly to the GP enabled secure element instead of the standard flash storage...

Thanks for comments and tips.
Regards,
STeN

Answer (score 0):

That seems a possibility. Supposedly the SEEK project claims it is possible to send APDU commands to SD card (even without firmware modification). However we do not know as [I answered you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6611810/nfc-card-emulation-android/6690356#6690356) to your other question, if the only other NFC-enabled android phone, that is SGSII in some variants, supports the required protocol. With SNS our only choice as you clearly state is using UICC, which myself haven't being able to reach yet, using SEEK patches.