# NFC Offhost routing to the UICC on the Nexus 5X and the Nexus 6P

Tags: android, nfc, apdu, hce, nxp-microcontroller

I am trying to configure the NFC chipset on the Nexus 5X (bullhead) or Nexus 6P (angler) to use the UICC as NFC offhost route for AIDs I declare in my OffHostApduService.

**Edit Jan 17, 2016:** *I've updated this question and also included the Nexus 6P as I had the chance to test it too and it behaves exactly like the 5X. So all previous findings from the 5X also seem to apply to the 6P.*

I managed to do this before on a Nexus 5 (hammerhead) thanks to Michael Roland's answer on [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21110392/kitkat-how-to-route-apdus-to-the-sim) and also on a Nexus 6 (shamu) (see the Nexus 6 [bcm2079x config in my Github repository](https://github.com/johnzweng/nexus_bcm2079x_configurations/tree/master/)).

However, the Nexus 5X (and also 6P) seem to be different:

- according to the ifixit teardown it contains a new chipset from NXP (PN548) and not broadcom bcm2079x like Nexus 4, 5 and 6).
- I can confirm that the device can read Mifare Classic tags (which strengthens the assumption that it contains a NXP chipset, as Broadcom chipsets didn't support Mifare Classic) and a device file `/dev/pn548` exists
- but strange enough it contains both, a `libnfc-brcm.conf` and `libnfc-nxp.conf` config file under `/system/etc/` (you can find these also in my Github repository)

As a starting point I modified the trace/log settings in *both* config files

- set `APPL_TRACE_LEVEL` to `0x05` for brcm
- set the `NXPLOG_*_LOGLEVEL` to `0x03` for nxp

What made me wonder was that I see a lot of the `BrcmNfcJni`messages in logcat during bootup, similiar to the ones I've seen on Nexus 5 and 6 (which I wouldn't have expected on a device with NXP chipset):

```
12-11 20:45:36.840 D/BrcmNfcJni( 3434): JNI_OnLoad: enter
12-11 20:45:36.841 I/BrcmNfcJni( 3434): NFC Service: loading nci JNI
12-11 20:45:36.841 D/BrcmNfcJni( 3434): register_com_android_nfc_NativeNfcManager: enter
12-11 20:45:36.841 D/BrcmNfcJni( 3434): PowerSwitch::initialize: level=PS-UNKNOWN (0)
12-11 20:45:36.923 D/BrcmNfcJni( 3434): PowerSwitch::initialize: desired screen-off state=1
12-11 20:45:36.923 D/BrcmNfcJni( 3434): register_com_android_nfc_NativeNfcManager: exit
12-11 20:45:36.923 D/BrcmNfcJni( 3434): register_com_android_nfc_NativeNfcTag
12-11 20:45:36.924 D/BrcmNfcJni( 3434): RoutingManager::RoutingManager(): default route is 0x00
12-11 20:45:36.924 D/BrcmNfcJni( 3434): RoutingManager::RoutingManager(): mOffHostEe=0xF2
12-11 20:45:36.924 D/BrcmNfcJni( 3434): RoutingManager::registerJniFunctions
12-11 20:45:36.924 D/BrcmNfcJni( 3434): JNI_OnLoad: exit
....
....
```

**Edit 1:**
I learned from the source that these *"BrcmNfc.."* log messages are emitted from the code in the **libnfc-nci** library. On previous devices the NCI (stands for: **N**FC **c**ontroller **i**nterface) was only used by Broadcom chipsets (I guess that's the reason why the code uses the prefix "Brcm" for logging). But apparently the new NXP chipsets now also use this standardized interface (which is good), and now we also see the "Brcm..." log messages even with a NXP chipset.

**Edit 3:**
Both phones (Nexus 5X and 6P) seem to contain the **NXP PN548/C2** NFC chipset running firmware version 10.01.19 (at least in the Android 6.0.1 release).

Of course there are also outputs from the NXP pn54x halimpl:

```
12-11 20:45:37.407 D/        ( 3434): phNxpLog_InitializeLogLevel: global =1, Fwdnld =3, extns =3,                 hal =3, tml =3, ncir     =3,                 ncix =3
12-11 20:45:37.408 D/NxpHal  ( 3434): Entering phNxpNciHal_init_monitor
12-11 20:45:37.408 D/NxpHal  ( 3434): Returning with SUCCESS
12-11 20:45:37.408 D/NxpTml  ( 3434): Opening port=/dev/pn54x
12-11 20:45:37.408 D/NxpTml  ( 3434): phTmlNfc_i2c_reset(), VEN level 1
12-11 20:45:37.527 D/NxpTml  ( 3434): phTmlNfc_i2c_reset(), VEN level 0
12-11 20:45:37.647 D/NxpTml  ( 3434): phTmlNfc_i2c_reset(), VEN level 1
12-11 20:45:37.667 D/NxpTml  ( 3434): PN54X - Tml Reader Thread Started................
12-11 20:45:37.667 D/NxpTml  ( 3434): PN54X - Read requested.....
12-11 20:45:37.667 D/NxpTml  ( 3434): PN54X - Invoking I2C Read.....
....
....
```

So as a first start I tried modifiying the `libnfc-nxp.conf` file, starting with parameters where the comments indicated a realtion to UICC or SWP:

```
 # No secure element 0x00
 # eSE               0x01
 # UICC              0x02
-NXP_DEFAULT_SE=0x03
+NXP_DEFAULT_SE=0x02
```

and also setting the `A0EC` tag in `NXP_CORE_CONF_EXTN` to `0x01` (as the comment indicates this tag is responsible for the SWP1 connector):

```
# A0EC      - SWP1 interface
#             0x00 - Disabled
#             0x01 - Enabled

-        A0, EC, 01, 00,
+        A0, EC, 01, 01,
```

Unfortunately this didn't work and I still receive the APDUs targeted to my offhost-service in the host system (as indicated by this logcat message: `E/HostEmulationManager( 3434): AID that was meant to go off-host was routed to host.`).

In later tries I also tried playing around with the parameters in `libnfc-brcm.conf` (as described by Michael Roland in the mentioned question above), but still was not successful.

## **QUESTION:**

- Has anybody managed to configure the NFC offhost routing on the Nexus 5X or 6P going to the UICC?
- Or maybe has some hints where I can look for further insights?
- Also a datasheet for the PN548 chipset would be very helpful.

**Edit 2:** 
I still did not find a working solution, but I pushed my tries until now to my [github repository under the **dev1** branch](https://github.com/johnzweng/nexus_bcm2079x_configurations/commits/dev1). I also pushed the resulting logcat outputs for each test. I am testing with a new unrooted Nexus 5X on Stock Android 6.0.1. (Edit: In the meantime I also got a Nexus 6P for testing but it behaves identically.) For modifying the config files on the system partition I temporalily boot into a sideloaded recovery image: (`fastboot boot twrp-2.8.7.2-bullhead.img`).

At the moment I always get this error (I also tried already with `0xf2` and `0xf4` as off-host routing target):

```
12-16 09:38:05.524 I/BrcmNfcNfa( 3480): NFA_EeAddAidRouting(): handle:<0xf3>
12-16 09:38:05.524 I/BrcmNfcNfa( 3480): nfa_ee_find_ecb ()
12-16 09:38:05.524 E/BrcmNfcNfa( 3480): Bad ee_handle or AID (len=14)
12-16 09:38:05.524 E/BrcmNfcJni( 3480): RoutingManager::addAidRouting: failed to route AID
```

Comment: Ok, I am understanding now why there is also a *libnfc-brcm.conf* config file: the reason is that the NXP PN548 chipset is using the standardized **libnfc-nci** host interface (and no longer the **libnfc-nxp** stack which used in previous devices with PN544). (see also [here in NXP's github repository](https://github.com/NXPNFCProject/NFC_NCIHAL_docs/blob/master/AN11762-Android_NXP_NFC_Setup_Guideline.pdf))
The **libnfc-brcm.conf** file simply is the config file for the **libnfc-nci** library, while the **libnfc-nxp.conf** nxp specific settings.

Comment: Update2: The chipset in my Nexus 5X testdevice seems to be a **NXP PN548C2** running firmware version: 10.01.19. Is there any way to determine if the SWP1 or SWP2 pin is connected to the UICC?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you already found out, the SWP lines aren't connected to the UICC slot. We usually don't do this for Nexus devices, since we don't support secure elements on the UICC in AOSP. The one exception to this is the Nexus 6 on Lollipop, which supported SoftCard mobile payments in the US (along with HCE). After SoftCard was acquired by Google, we removed the code to support UICCs again in Marshmallow.

I'm surprised BTW that this worked on N5 - it was supposed to not have SWP connected either. Perhaps this wasn't done correctly on all devices.

Comment: Hi @martijn-coenen, thank you very much for your valuable input. I assume this means I don't have to look further at the Nexus 6P as it also doesn't have a SWP connection to the UICC.

Currently I've installed the OpenMobile API on my Nexus 6 (shamu) running Android 6.0.1. I was looking forward to switch over to one of the new nexus devices while still being able to use my UICC-based banking card (https://www.bankomatkarte-mobil.at/).

Comment: Yep the 6P is the same. Note that this is what we told both Huawei and LGE to do, I haven't actually opened either device to verify this. But on the (early) schematics they were not connected.

Comment: Thanks again @martijn-coenen for this info. If I get hands on a 6P maybe I will still try and check (as it also works unexpectedly on my LG Nexus 5).

Comment: I got a Nexus 6P for testing and out of curiosity I did the same tests. I can confirm now that all my findings also apply to the Nexus 6P. It behaves identically. Also on the Nexus 6P the SWP line is not connected to the UICC.

Answer (score 5):

### Short answer:

**NFC Offhost routing to the UICC seems not to be possible on the Nexus 5X (*edit:* and also on Nexus 6P).** As far as I understand, the SWP lines of the NFC chip are not connected to the UICC (on both phones).

**Edit 1**:
In the meantime I got hands on a Nexus 6P made all the same tests like I did on the 5X. I can confirm now that the 6P behaves identically. I even got the same errors in logcat when calling the **`phNxpNciHal_SwpTest`** function. So also on the Nexus 6P the SWP line is not connected to the UICC.

### Details:

After numerous unsuccessful tries with different config file settings I looked into the NXP implementation within the [libnfc-hci](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/libnfc-nci/+/android-6.0.1_r3/halimpl/pn54x/) library and found the interesting function "**phNxpNciHal_SwpTest**" in **"self-test/phNxpNciHal_SelfTest.c"** which according to the comment, seems to test the SWP lines:

```
/*******************************************************************************
 **
 ** Function         phNxpNciHal_SwpTest
 **
 ** Description      Test function to validate the SWP line. SWP line number is
 **                  is sent as parameter to the API.
 **
 ** Returns          NFCSTATUS_SUCCESS if successful,otherwise NFCSTATUS_FAILED.
 **
 *******************************************************************************/
```

I then modified the `hal/phNxpNciHal.c` file (added lots of debugging log statements just for better understanding the flow and) added 2 calls to this test function. First I tried adding it at the end of the  `phNxpNciHal_open` function (see my changes [here on GitHub](https://github.com/johnzweng/AOSP_external_libnfc-nci/commit/03a622743ff1cb761dba37e2342dbfcf59ff2708)) and later also tried to add it at the beginning of the `phNxpNciHal_close`  function before actually closing the NFCC interface, just to be sure that UICC and everything is initialized at this point in time (see commit 6b33149 on my GitHub account linked above).

During the tests a SWP-capable UICC was inserted in the device.

Unfortunately all calls to `phNxpNciHal_SwpTest` returned an error (for both SWP lines). Look for the string "**phNxpNciHal_SwpTest - FAILED**" in the logcat output below:

```
12-22 08:48:01.597 D/NxpHal  ( 3691): JZJZ phNxpNciHal_SwpTest - testing SWP line 0x01
12-22 08:48:01.597 D/NxpHal  ( 3691): JZJZ phNxpNciHal_SwpTest - performing test...
12-22 08:48:01.597 D/NxpTml  ( 3691): PN54X - Write requested.....
12-22 08:48:01.597 D/NxpTml  ( 3691): PN54X - Invoking I2C Write.....
12-22 08:48:01.598 D/NxpNciX ( 3691): len =   4 > 20000101
12-22 08:48:01.598 D/NxpTml  ( 3691): PN54X - I2C Write successful.....
12-22 08:48:01.598 D/NxpTml  ( 3691): PN54X - Posting Fresh Write message.....
12-22 08:48:01.598 D/NxpTml  ( 3691): PN54X - Tml Writer Thread Running................
12-22 08:48:01.598 D/NxpHal  ( 3691): write successful status = 0x0
12-22 08:48:01.598 D/NxpHal  ( 3691): JZJZ performTest: write success. staring read locked from NFCC..
12-22 08:48:01.598 D/NxpHal  ( 3691): JZJZ readLocked: semaphore created, starting tml nfc read..
12-22 08:48:01.598 D/NxpHal  ( 3691): JZJZ readLocked: read returned..
12-22 08:48:01.598 E/NxpHal  ( 3691): TML Read status error status = 16f
12-22 08:48:01.598 D/NxpHal  ( 3691): JZJZ performTest: at clean_and_return label.. concurrency_unlock..
12-22 08:48:01.598 D/NxpHal  ( 3691): JZJZ phNxpNciHal_SwpTest - performing test FAILED...will break loop
12-22 08:48:01.598 D/NxpHal  ( 3691): phNxpNciHal_SwpTest - FAILED
12-22 08:48:01.598 D/NxpHal  ( 3691): phNxpNciHal_SwpTest - end


12-22 08:48:01.598 D/NxpHal  ( 3691): JZJZ: SWP1 test done, will perform SWP2 test now.
12-22 08:48:01.598 D/NxpHal  ( 3691): JZJZ phNxpNciHal_SwpTest - start
12-22 08:48:01.598 D/NxpHal  ( 3691): JZJZ phNxpNciHal_SwpTest - testing SWP line 0x02
12-22 08:48:01.598 D/NxpHal  ( 3691): JZJZ phNxpNciHal_SwpTest - performing test..
12-22 08:48:01.598 D/NxpHal  ( 3691): JZJZ performTest: concurrency locked. write locked to NFCC..
12-22 08:48:01.598 D/NxpTml  ( 3691): PN54X - Write requested.....
12-22 08:48:01.598 D/NxpTml  ( 3691): PN54X - Invoking I2C Write.....
12-22 08:48:01.599 D/NxpNciX ( 3691): len =   4 > 20000101
12-22 08:48:01.599 D/NxpTml  ( 3691): PN54X - I2C Write successful.....
12-22 08:48:01.599 D/NxpTml  ( 3691): PN54X - Posting Fresh Write message.....
12-22 08:48:01.599 D/NxpTml  ( 3691): PN54X - Tml Writer Thread Running................
12-22 08:48:01.599 D/NxpHal  ( 3691): write successful status = 0x0
12-22 08:48:01.599 D/NxpHal  ( 3691): JZJZ performTest: write success. staring read locked from NFCC..
12-22 08:48:01.599 D/NxpHal  ( 3691): JZJZ readLocked: semaphore created, starting tml nfc read..
12-22 08:48:01.599 D/NxpHal  ( 3691): JZJZ readLocked: read returned..
12-22 08:48:01.599 E/NxpHal  ( 3691): TML Read status error status = 16f
12-22 08:48:01.599 D/NxpHal  ( 3691): JZJZ performTest: at clean_and_return label.. concurrency_unlock..
12-22 08:48:01.599 D/NxpHal  ( 3691): JZJZ phNxpNciHal_SwpTest - performing test FAILED...will break loop.
12-22 08:48:01.599 D/NxpHal  ( 3691): phNxpNciHal_SwpTest - FAILED
12-22 08:48:01.599 D/NxpHal  ( 3691): phNxpNciHal_SwpTest - end
12-22 08:48:01.599 D/NxpHal  ( 3691): JZJZ: SWP2 test done.
```

#### Conclusion:

Without further knowledge of hardware details of the **NXP PN548/C2** chipset, I assume this means that both SWP lines of the chipset are not connected in the Nexus 5X (bullhead) phone.

If anybody has more insight in this topic, please feel free correct me! :)