# how to connect a device with nfc chip(twinlinx mymax nfc chip ) using bluetooth

Tags: iphone, android, java-me, bluetooth, nfc

Hi In my  android project i m planning to use TwinLinx Mymax NFC chip to make a any phone nfc enable.
but i dont know  how the phone communicate with the nfc chip using bluetooth.I think they will provide some sdk or api for this.
any type to supporting link or code that can help me .
so please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was communicating with them some time ago. They can provide you MyMax Development Kit:
*...The Development Kit offer is designed for you to develop applications on a mobile phone and connect to the MyMax sticker. The kit comes with examples and source code to enable you to quickly understand the procedures and start working with the sticker on a wide range of phones which are listed on our Web site. A USB PC reader is included to re-charge the sticker...*

They asked 2000 EUR for the kit, so I did not purchase it.

BR
STeN

Comment: thanks of your response , I have heard about the another way to access nfc is using nfc enabled micro SD card , have you any idea about that.

Comment: Hi, you have 3 possibilities: (1)TwinLinx Mymax NFC or similar sticker, (2)the phone with built-in NFC controller(Google Nexus S, Nokia C7, Meego N9...) or (3)NFC enabled SD card or other peripheral.Do you know about any NFC enabled micro SD card, which is being commercially available? I was using the SD card with secure element, but not with the NFC - for this I was using the phone with built-in NFC controller - but this is not the best and the most secure way. For the secure element use SIM card, built-in se or NFC-WI/S2C micro SD card (HW is not on the market)... WHAT you want to achieve?BR

Comment: See here also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6992869/android-and-symbian-nfc-mobile-development-questions-and-answers-faq