# Beginning NFC application development

Tags: java, android, api, nfc

I am going to build an client-server service that will control the security of a house(who comes in and who comes out). I want the identification to be made via nfc communication and especialy between a nfc-android phone and a nfc reader connected to a pc. So i am thinking of 2 programms. one for the phone and one for the pc( +1 for the server if any). I want data to be saved to both phone and pc. Is this possible via nfc? can the phone read and write data via nfc?

I am thinking of using java for both programms. Do we know for any nfc api? (i have a nxp chip on my device)
What reader should i buy? any recomendations?

Answer (score 0):

In order to make the application you have to save certain information (e.g. user id) in a secure place. This is the problem, since the phone normally does not allow running in card emulation mode and do not allow to access the secure element - more you can read there: [Android and Symbian NFC mobile development questions and answers (FAQ)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6992869/android-and-symbian-nfc-mobile-development-questions-and-answers-faq).

Anyway it seems that the Mifare 4K can be used... Might be the p2p mode with the SD card secure element is also a way there...

BR
STeN

Comment: So will i be able to write and read data to the phone? i don't care if it to Mifare 4k or the SD through p2p!!! i am going anyway to buy a nfc reader...

Answer (score 0):

Android does let you now to use your phone like it is a nfc-tag.
This is called "Host based Card Emulation". 
On your phone, you can either let android do the magic and after the transaction is finished read the status in your app, or you can have your app control the whole process.

See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/hce.html