# How to make an android phone act as Contactless smart card?

Tags: android, nfc, smartcard

I would like to know how to make the android phone act as contactless card to transfer certain data to POS. Is there any specific Intent we should try to catch and how to communicate with that eternal POS via NFC.

Comment: maybe you can take advatage of using Bluetooth...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am afraid it is not directly possible. You need to enable [NFC Card emulation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6690356/34880) which involves recompiling a custom firmware image. I am not aware if beyond Android 2.3.6 emulation is already enabled by default (so Google Wallet can be used). If you want to enable card emulation by recompiling the system by yourself [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7595889/34880) you have more information. At any rate secure element of the emulated card can not be accessed (see information following the links) directly from an application by any means.

Comment: That is true even for the latest version of Android. Card emulation is not enabled.

Answer (score 0):

In order to contact with a contactless smart card you need to use the pending intents and foreground dispatch. Now regarding the contactless terminal i'm not sure.